# How to resize correctly a panel automatically when another panel is dinamically moving java swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

i am building an app who has two jPanels in the jFrame, one of them is moving right side when i press this button:

[image]

If i press the button, a jPanel appears dinamically.

[image]

My main problem is when i maximise the jframe i dont know what can i use to resize both panels, because if i try to use a different layout that it has actually (AbsoluteLayot), the jPanel1 (that comes with the button) can´t  be in outside of the jFrame to do the effect that i am trying to do...

[image]

My initComponents, to do what can i modify:

```
private void initComponents() {


        panel_menu.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(580, 110));


        panel_fondo.add(jPanel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(70, 30, 340, 340));

        getContentPane().add(panel_fondo, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
```

Any help? thank you!

Comment: Please post your code. See [mre]

Comment: Edited, i didn´t put it because i didn´t do anything apart from create the two jPanels with the specifications that i said in the question..

Comment: I am afraid the code posted is not mre. It is not **M** and not **R**.

Comment: re Edited, i say it again, i didn´t put code  because i just have created the two jPanels and nothing else, and the question it´s not a problem code.

Comment: Use a BorderLayout. Never use an bsolute layout. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html. Or use a JSplitPane. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for your answer! But if i use the BorderLayout i couldn´t control the jPanel1 with the button as i show in the image. Because it won´t let me put the jPanel1 outside from the jFrame as i show... Any solution?

Comment: A panel can't be outside of the window. The left panel should be on the left of the border layout. It should only display the button when it's collapsed, and display everything when it's expanded.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes i did your recommendation to use borderLayout and works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using the recommendation of @JBNizet, i have used the BorderLayout https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html to fit according to my specifications. And working fine now, The button is placed in north direction, the jPanel2 in west direction and jPanel1 in the center.

Comment: I wonder whether you are not looking for the functionality of a **`JSplitPane`**.

Comment: Of course i did, but the things that i have in mind i realized that for now is better to learn and use the BorderLayout functionalities.